# I "random" meaning with known probability?

Tags: terminology

Can I say that a phenominon(e.g. like a coin flip)
Is not deterministic but also not 50/50
,rather completly unpredictable ?
Is there a term for such behaviour ?
Is that what "random" mean or is random apply for 50/50 ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the mathematical definition of randomness, not about philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

Determinism typically means (something like) being predictable in principle, if given adequate information and computational power.  If I understand what you mean by these terms, then I would say that a coin flip is both deterministic but also unpredictable due to the fact that we do not in fact have the adequate information and/or computational power necessary to make a prediction within acceptable measurement error.